# Is it safe to delete diretly from the newsletter_subscriber's table?

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2

I recently turned on email address confirmation for visitors signing up for the newsletter. I'd now like to delete all the newsletter subscriptions made prior to this.

Whilst the database table `newsletter_subscriber` does have a date column `change_status_at`, this column is not displayed in the admin, so I can't filter and delete just the old subscriptions.

Ideally I'd like to just run a simple query against the database, which will delete just what I want. However, I'm really cautious about running any queries directly against the Magento database as I'm worried about unexpected interactions.

I have searched the database schema for forign key references to columns in the `newsletter_subscriber` table, and can't find any.

Is there anyway to be sure that this is a standalone table and safe to delete from?

Answer (score 0):

Always better to use magento approach to delete records since it can trigger all needed event, action, etc. 
But in current case I don't see a big deal if you delete it by subscribers id